# How to check whether Cart contain any nominal(isRecurring) item Magento

Tags: magento-1.7, cart, magento-1.5

How to check whether Cart contain any nominal(isRecurring) item in Magento.

I have found one function isRecurring but i don't know how to use this function in cart. Can anyone know any other code(function) to check nominal item in cart ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: where do you wanna check this? In the cart page or in checkout process or somewhere else?

Comment: cart as well as in onestepcheckout page

Answer (score 1):

Try `Mage::getSingleton('sales/quote')->getShippingAddress()->getAllNominalItems()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer which worked in my case

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');

$items = $cart->getItems();
  foreach ($items as $item) { 
    if($item->getProduct()->getIsRecurring()){
       your code.............
     }
    }
```

Hope this help some one